# Registrar forwarding HTTP to HTTP, getting certificate error on some browsers

Tags: dns-hosting, domain-registrar

I am researching my error for some time now, and I do not seem to get a sufficient answer on my own:

I configured our Domain on our registrar to forward an URL from `http://example.com` to `http://www.another-example.com`. This `another-example.com` domain on their side have a forwarding from HTTP to HTTPS. So far so good. I tested it with freshly installed browsers and it seemed to work. Additionally I also configured this same thing for `http://www.example.com`.

Today I got a message, that that some customers get an error in their browser, that they are hitting an HTTP site, which is a security risk, and they have to click `continue` (we all now this error message), which then triggers the redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.another-example.com` an then to `https://www.another-example.com`.

So I tested this of course, and surprisingly it always works with `http://example.com`, but with the `www` prefix it does not. Why? is it because `http://www.example.com` points first to `http://example.com` or does it have some other reason?

Comment: `www.example.com` is not the same thing as `example.com`, it is *another* name and you have to request the certificate for it explicitly. if the same virtual host is going to serve both, its certificate must have both of them in the SAN field. And, probably, `another-example.com` and `www.another-example.com` too. (By the way, this question was already asked millions times here.)

Comment: Yeah, thx, I did not find this link. Closing my question.